# Ubuntu 16.04, when I switch to HDMI audio out, all audio and video is slowed down.

Tags: sound, hdmi, output

It is a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04, and everything works fine. Sound works fine and video work fine. When I switch to HDMI audio output, all playback is slowed down. Both audio and video are slowed down, so I am not sure if it is an issue with sound or video. Have tried youtube videos, and .mp4 videos on the laptop. I'm not really sure where to start. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: At least for me the video works when sound is muted. Annoying as hell...

Comment: And I had it on 15.x too. Running Dell E7250.

Comment: I got the same problem. But it does not happen 100% of the time. Sometimes if I restart the problem does not happen.